# Split a string only by spaces that are outside quotes

Tags: bash

I know, this was asked a bilion times, but i yet did not find the optimal solution for my specific case.

I'm receving a string like this:

```
VAR1="some text here" VAR2='some another text' some script --with --some=args
```

how do i split the string like this: (most preferable in pure bash)

```
VAR1="some text here"
VAR2='some another text'
some script --with --some=args
```

`set -- $str` result in `VAR1="some`

`set -- "$str"` returns entire string

`eval set -- "$str"` result in `VAR1=some text here`

sure, i could add quotes to the string returned by `eval`, but i get highly untrusted input so `eval` is not a option at all.

Important: there can be from zero to unlimited VARs and they can be single or double quoted

Also, the `VAR` is a fake name here, it can in fact be anything.

Thanks.

Comment: What's on the other end? If you can force the list to be serialized with `printf '%q '` by a trusted process (while it's still a list and not a string), you can make use of eval safe even if you don't trust what's going into the serialization.

Comment: no way to get it serialized, it is user input from a SaaS, and each 10th user knows how to own a system :)

Comment: Can quotes be nested `VAR="a'b"` or escaped `VAR="a\"b"`?

Comment: @choroba `"a'b"` is legal; `"a\"b"` is not, but `$'a\'b'` _is_.

Comment: What about `VAR1="ab"x VAR2='ab'"cd"`?

Comment: @choroba Both those are legal.

Comment: stuff like this should be dropped, only "correct" syntax accepted

Comment: it is legal but not correct for this concret situation. we can impose some restrictions on input

Comment: I am not clear on the exact constraints on the input. Are you guaranteed to see all variable-type statements followed by at most one string not delimited by quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huh, seems i'm late to the party :)

Here is how i'm dealing with environment vars passed before script.

First off all, `escape_args` function will escape spaces "inside" passed vars,

so if user pass `VAR="foo bar"`, it will become `VAR=foo\0040bar`.

```
function escape_args {
  local str=''
  local opt=''
  for c in $1; do
    if [[ "$c" =~ ^[[:alnum:]]+=[\"|\'] ]]; then
      if [[ "${c: -1}" =~ [\"|\']  ]]; then
        str="$str $( echo $c | xargs )"
      else
        # first opt chunk
        # entering collector
        opt="$c"
      fi
    else
      if [ -z "$opt" ]; then
        # not inside collector
        str="$str $c"
      else
        # inside collector
        if [[ "${c: -1}" =~ [\"|\']  ]]; then
          # last opt chunk
          # adding collected chunks and this last one to str
          str="$str $( echo "$opt\0040$c" | xargs )"
          # leaving collector
          opt=''
        else
          # middle opt chunk
          opt="$opt\0040$c"
        fi
      fi
    fi
  done
  echo "$str"
}
```

Lets test it against a modified version of your input:

```
s="VAR1=\"some text here\" VAR2='some another text' VAR3=\"noSpaces\" VAR4='noSpacesToo' VAR5=noSpacesNoQuotes some script --with --some=args"

echo $(escape_args "$s")

VAR1=some\0040text\0040here VAR2=some\0040another\0040text VAR3=noSpaces VAR4=noSpacesToo VAR5=noSpacesNoQuotes some script --with --some=args
```

see, all vars are space-escaped and quotes removed, so `declare` will work correctly.

Now you can iterate through the parts of your input.

Here is an example how you can declare vars and run the script:

```
cmd=''
for c in $(escape_args "$s"); do
  [[ "$c" =~ ^[[:alnum:]]+= ]] && declare "$(echo -e $c)" && continue
  cmd="$cmd $c"
done

echo VAR1 is set to $VAR1
echo VAR2 is set to $VAR2
echo VAR3 is set to $VAR3
echo VAR4 is set to $VAR4
echo VAR5 is set to $VAR5
echo $cmd
```

This iterator is doing two simple things:

- declaring a var if the chunk matching `SOME_VAR=` expression
- adding the chunk to the final cmd otherwise

so the output will be:

```
VAR1 is set to some text here
VAR2 is set to some another text
VAR3 is set to noSpaces
VAR4 is set to noSpacesToo
VAR5 is set to noSpacesNoQuotes
some script --with --some=args
```

Is this close to your needs?

Comment: that's a great idea to escape vars then feely iterate over input! trying it

Comment: works just fine, thank you! is there a way to give an +100 instead of +1? :)

Answer (score 4):

It's not remotely close to pure bash -- but Python has a `shlex` module which attempts to provide shell-compatible lexing.

```
>>> import shlex, pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(shlex.split('''VAR1="some text here" VAR2='some another text' some script --with --some=args'''))
['VAR1=some text here',
 'VAR2=some another text',
 'some',
 'script',
 '--with',
 '--some=args']
```

The following, more complete example uses this Python module from bash, with NUL-delimited stream providing unambiguous transport:

```
shlex() {
  python -c $'import sys, shlex\nfor arg in shlex.split(sys.stdin):\n\tsys.stdout.write(arg)\n\tsys.stdout.write(\"\\0\")'
}
args=()
while IFS='' read -r -d ''; do
  args+=( "$REPLY" )
done < <(shlex <<<$'VAR1="some text here" VAR2=\'some another text\' some script --with --some=args')
printf '%s\n' "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: I find it ironic that `shlex` is built to behave like bash, but then must be used in bash as a workaround for a missing direct api

Comment: @jozxyqk, `shlex` is built to behave like POSIX sh, not bash. Bash has a number of extensions to the standard which shlex doesn't support, such as `$''` quoting (with backslash-escape sequences, but no evaluation)

Answer (score 2):

You can play with the following pure bash code. It goes over the input character by character and tries to keep flags about being inside/outside of quotes.

```
#! /bin/bash 
string=$(cat <<'EOF'
VAR1="some text here" VAR2='some another text' VAR3="a'b" VAR4='a"b' VAR5="a\"b" VAR6='a'"'"'b' some script --with --some=args
EOF
)
echo "$string"

results=()
result=''
inside=''
for (( i=0 ; i<${#string} ; i++ )) ; do
    char=${string:i:1}
    if [[ $inside ]] ; then
        if [[ $char == \\ ]] ; then
            if [[ $inside=='"' && ${string:i+1:1} == '"' ]] ; then
                let i++
                char=$inside
            fi
        elif [[ $char == $inside ]] ; then
            inside=''
        fi
    else
        if [[ $char == ["'"'"'] ]] ; then
            inside=$char
        elif [[ $char == ' ' ]] ; then
            char=''
            results+=("$result")
            result=''
        fi
    fi
    result+=$char
done
if [[ $inside ]] ; then
    echo Error parsing "$result"
    exit 1
fi

for r in "${results[@]}" ; do
    echo "< $r >"
done
```

Comment: +1++++ , now that's maniacal bash coding! ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: It's not quite true to how the shell behaves -- `VAR5`, in particular, is something that a POSIX shell wouldn't parse this way, and the `$''` extension isn't handled.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stream editor to modify the text.  You could first grab the variables using a regular expression, and replace them with empty quotes.  Append quotes to the beginning and end.  At this stage you should have:

```
VAR1="some text here" 
VAR2='some another text'
```

in separate strings, and the original string will look like:

```
"""""some script --with --some=args"
```

standard command line parsing will return:

```
""
""
"some script --with --some=args"
```

Throw out the empty strings, and you should have what you want left over. This is a hacky (potential) solution, and I would urge testing/thinking about it a bit before using something like this.

Comment: You could use awk or the built-in regex features of bash instead of sed, if you wanted to.