# Bash to split string with space separated value with double quote

Tags: bash, shell

In my shell script, there is a string to keep all arguments

```
arg_str="arg1=ABC      arg2=123 arg3= arg4=\"consecutive      spaces and \\\"escaped quote\\\" shall be preserved within quotes\""
```

I want to split the `arg_str` by space but keep anything as is within in double quotes. The expected result is:

```
arg1=ABC
arg2=123
arg3=
arg4=consecutive      spaces and \"escaped quote\" shall be preserved within quotes
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12827764/1524900) can split by spaces outside double quotes, but it cannot preserve consecutive spaces within double quotes.

**EDIT**
Why I need this? I'm designing a shell script to accept dynamic arguments -- both arg name and value are dynamic, e.g. `myscript.sh arg1=ABC arg2=123 arg3= arg4="consecutive      spaces and \"escaped quote\" shall be preserved within quotes"`. I'm not good at bash. Someone mentioned `getopts`, it seems it not suitable for the situation of dynamic args.

Comment: Using a string for this is fundamentally broken. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Well, why would you ever want to keep it in such a string? There is also `getopts`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to give `perl` (which is available on most of the Linux/Unix distributions) a chance then it is doable:

```
arg_str="arg1=ABC      arg2=123 arg3= arg4=\"consecutive      spaces and \\\"escaped quote\\\" shall be preserved within quotes\""

perl -pe 's/"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\h+/$&\n/g' <<< "$arg_str"
```

```
arg1=ABC
arg2=123
arg3=
arg4="consecutive      spaces and \"escaped quote\" shall be preserved within quotes"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nPB4jr/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `"`: Match opening `"`
- `[^"\\]*`: Match a character that is not `"` and not a `\`
- `(?:`: Start a non-capturing group

  - `\\`: Match a `\`
  - `.`: Match any character
  - `[^"\\]*`: Match a character that is not `"` and not a `\`
- `)*`: End non-capturing group. `*` means repeat this group 0 or more times
- `"`: Match closing `"`
- `(*FAIL)` behaves like a failing negative assertion and is a synonym for `(?!)`
- `(*SKIP)` defines a point beyond which the regex engine is not allowed to backtrack when the subpattern fails later
- `|`: OR
- `\h+`: Match 1 or more horizontal whitespaces

---

If you don't want `perl` then here is a `gnu awk` based solution:

```
awk -v FPAT='[^[:blank:]]*"[^\\\\"]*(\\\\.[^\\\\"]*)*"|[^[:blank:]]+' 
'{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' <<< "$arg_str"
```

```
arg1=ABC
arg2=123
arg3=
arg4="consecutive      spaces and \"escaped quote\" shall be preserved within quotes"
```

Comment: I'd somehow suggest not to encourage the OP to work on broken by design problem.

Comment: There is no intention to encourage/discourage any design pattern. All I see in question is a requirement to split an input with quotes and escaped quotes which needs to be split on *horizontal whitespaces* that are outside quotes.

Comment: @OP: After reading your edited question where it appears that this string seems to be coming as command line argument to your script. If that's the case why not just use `printf '<%s>\n' "$@"` and check output.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, I use this to parse command line dynamic arguments. I'm new to shell scripting and not sure if it is a good solution. Your perl and printf version work great and solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you would want to do this, but here is a bash way to do it :

```
#!/bin/bash

#myscript.sh arg1=ABC arg2=123 arg3= arg4="consecutive      spaces and \"escaped quote\" shall be preserved within quotes"

for arg in "${@}"
do
    argname="${arg%%=*}"
    argvalue="${arg##*=}"
    parameters[$argname]="$argvalue"
done

printf "\n" 
echo  "${parameters[arg2]}"
```

Regards!